# Creating new SBT project for Scala using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

I have Eclipse (Kepler) and the Scala plugin (http://scala-ide.org/) installed.
With Eclipse, I can create a new Scala project, but its not an `sbt` project, so cannot add dependencies.

What is the best way to create a new skeleton `sbt` project, either within Eclipse, or one which can be imported into Eclipse?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/ ?

Answer (score 3):

Create the `sbt` project yourself, then use the [sbt-eclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/) plugin to generate your eclipse project. This should make a `.project` and `.classpath` file in your sbt project directory. In Eclipse, use the "import existing projects" dialog.